# Disable PHP for a subdirectory in lighttpd

Tags: php, webserver, lighttpd

how can I disable PHP for a subdirectory in lighttpd.

I tried

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/home/www/userfiles" {

   fastcgi.server = ()

}
```

but this does not work.

Thanks

Mebus